# When making JDBC Authentication in Spring Boot, do I have to use the default 'users' table?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to use JDBC Authentication in Spring Boot. I am trying to use a different table than the default 'users'. But with this method

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT email as USERNAME, PASSWORD as password FROM [user_account] WHERE email=?");
}
```

With the given table schema:
[![f][1]][1]

I get the following error:

```
17:34:29.800 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] INFO  o.s.j.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
17:34:29.806 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] WARN  o.s.s.o.p.endpoint.TokenEndpoint - Handling error: [![enter image description here][2]][2]InternalAuthenticationServiceException, PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT email as USERNAME, PASSWORD as password FROM [user_account] WHERE email=?]; The index 3 is out of range.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 3 is out of range.
```

What can I do to use my own user data table for JDBC Authentication?

Comment: _As a side note:_ you haven't properly provided your table schema in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you update your query by appending enabled as the third paramater to select

`SELECT email as USERNAME, PASSWORD as password, enabled FROM [user_account] WHERE email=?`

Comment: oh that solves the problem, thanks. Can you also explain the case with the AuthoritiesByUsernameQuery?

Comment: update the table name that you created `select username, role from [user_account_role] where email=?`

Comment: my role schema does consist id instead of username:

Comment: you dont have email in your role schema like you do on your users schema ?

Comment: nope, can i connect two tables, since users schema also have id

Comment: ok try this `select user.username, role.role from user user, user_roles role  where user.userid = role.userid and user.email=?` please fix the field namings

Comment: why do we write from user user, can you please explain your variables?

Comment: if you need to join two or more tables, provide an alias and its easier to refer their fields